# On Redhat server, can I increase /var online and how to do it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, redhat

On Redhat server, can I increase /var online and how to do it? I have free space in the VG.

Answer (score 1):

run vgdisplay to check free space

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               XYZ
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               919.97 GiB
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29439
  Alloc PE / Size       29439 / 919.97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       250 / 2 GiB
```

Suppose I want to allocate full 250 Free PE to /var, run below to extend /var. In my case there was no free space so I just created a dummy number.

```
#lvextend -l +250 /dev/<vg_name>/<Var LV name>
```

After extending re-size it.

```
#resize2fs /dev/<vg_name>/<Var LV name>
```